# Trying to Compile/Run CPP MSYS2 but Receiving "No such file or directory" Error Message

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, 64-bit, msys2

I wrote a .cpp program on Notepad as a test run.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
  
}
```

I then installed mingw-w64-x8664-gcc onto MSYS2 for my 64-bit Windows 10 PC and directed the MSYS2 terminal using the full path name (the path was copy-pasted from my files):

```
g++ C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop\C++ Programming 21_11_2023\21nov2023program.cpp -o 21nov.cpp
```

My compilation was terminated with the following message:

```
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: 21nov2023program.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I tried the following command before attempting to compile it again, to no effect:

```
cd /c/
```

I also tried this command before attempting to compile it once more:

```
set PATH = C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop\C++ Programming 21_11_2023\21nov2023program.cpp
```

But I encountered the same error message as before. How should I go about compiling and running my program?

In response to a few comments, I tried this and got the following results:

```
cd /c/

g++ "C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop\C++Programming_21_11_2023\21nov2023program.cpp" -o 21nov.cpp

C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file 21nov.cpp: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Whats the _exact_ error message?

Comment: Make sure that your no part of your full pathname contains any space characters. If it does contain space characters my advice is to reconsider using spaces in paths when programming in c++ or c because a space separates different arguments on the command line forcing you to have to quote paths to get around the issue.

Comment: For msys2 you may want to use the mingw terminal and put your c++ code in the home folder it creates for you. This may be `C:\msys64\home\yourusername` I have created a folder inside of this for the StackOverflow code I test using MinGW.

Comment: Please show the exact command you're using. Come on, you're asking about "No such file or directory" and you censor the path? Also please show the exact error message.

Comment: You're missing a space after `g++` in the first command. If you do it inside the MSYS2 terminal, you also need `'` around the path (in some other shells you'd use `"` instead). Also it's recommended to not have spaces in the path (rename your directory), then you can spell the path as `/c/users/blah/blah/21nov2023program.cpp1` without the quotes (quotes are needed if you either have spaces or are trying to use backslashes in path in MSYS2 shell). Also PATH is for executables, not for general files, and even then it's supposed to contain only directory paths.

Comment: *"In response to a few comments..."* Please post a comment starting with `@username` to respond, otherwise we don't get notifications. *"`Permission denied`"* First of all, the filename after `-o` is supposed to be an .exe: `-o 21nov.exe` or just `-o 21nov` (then `.exe` is added automatically). Second, try `cd`-ing to some other directory, e.g. `C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop\C++Programming_21_11_2023`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It worked. Thank you!